ASP.NET Core 8 MVC : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
I keep getting this error when trying to create a directory:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\tp_re\source\repos\soppingaMVC\soppingaMVC\wwwroot\productImages'.'

The code:
System.IO.File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\wwwroot\productImages\" + HttpContext.Session.GetString("guid"));

This is the folder setup in my visual studio:

Not sure the path looks correct, but getting the error, am I missing something?
The files Physical location


The image shows the solution structure, which may not reflect the actual folder structure on your file system, can you confirm the actual directories are matching the paths you're using?

Yes it does, i checked in the file browser, i have updated the question

Checked dir perms?

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\wwwroot\productImages\" + HttpContext.Session.GetString("guid"));


So you're saying change it to "CreateDirectory"?
